# Translating XAML to C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I'm creating a ListBox in my C# code, and I need to write this code in C#, although I'm not exactly sure how to do it,

http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/silverlight-and-wpf-how-to-make-items-stretch-horizontally-in-a-listbox/

```
<Grid>
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
<ListBox Margin="100" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding}"
                Background="LightYellow"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
</Grid>
```

More specificly, how do I write this in C#

```
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
```

And

```
ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what benefit is gained by handling UI elements with c# instead of XAML?

Comment: Have you made an attempt?  What research have you done?  Generally the help pages show both XAML and C# code-behind examples.

Comment: What about your `ItemTemplate`?  Do you need to define that in C# as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the style via:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.HorizontalContentAlignment, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch));
```

You can then set this via:

```
listBox.ItemContainerStyle = style;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by Reed Copsey will work.

A naive alternative (though honestly likely more "efficient," since it's explicit) is to set the HorizontalContentAlignment property of your ListBoxItem objects to HorizontalAlignment.Stretch, when you construct them (if you're also constructing them in code).

```
ListBoxItem i = new ListBoxItem { HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch };
```